# Cannot cast View to Switch

Tags: java, android, casting, switch-statement

I need a really simple thing done, but I keep getting errors. I have multiple switches with each a distinct id. Everytime I use (Switch)findViewById(), it gives me the following error: Cannot cast View to Switch. s is defined as a Switch.
I did some research and I have tried to clean my project and delete my R file, but it still doesn't work.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
switches = weekprogram.getSwitches(day); //returns an arraylist with switches


            for (int j = 0; j < switches.size(); j++) {
                switch (j) {
                case 5:
                    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeBOne);

                    s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchOne);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeBTwo);

                    s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchTwo);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeBThree);

                    s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchThree);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeBFour);

                    s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchFour);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeBFive);

                    s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchFive);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeBSix);

                    s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchSix);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeBseven);

                    s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchSeven);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeBEight);

                    s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchEight);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeBNine);

                    s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchNine);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.timeBTen);

                    s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switchTen);
                    break;

                }
...
}
```

XML File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundforapp"
 android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.hti_thermostat.SelectedDay$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/timeBNine"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeBTen"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timeBTen"
    android:text="09:30 AM"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:onClick="setTimeButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/timeBEight"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeBNine"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timeBFive"
    android:text="08:30 AM"
    android:textSize="13sp" 
    android:onClick="setTimeButton"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/timeBseven"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeBEight"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timeBEight"
    android:text="07:30 AM"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:onClick="setTimeButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/timeBSix"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeBseven"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timeBseven"
    android:text="06:30 AM"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:onClick="setTimeButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/timeBTen"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timeBEight"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:text="10:30 AM"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:onClick="setTimeButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/timeBFive"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timeBFour"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="05:30 AM"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:onClick="setTimeButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/timeBFour"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeBFive"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timeBThree"
    android:text="04:30 AM"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:onClick="setTimeButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/timeBThree"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeBFour"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/DayofWeek"
    android:text="03:30 AM"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:onClick="setTimeButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/timeBTwo"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeBThree"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/timeBThree"
    android:text="02:30 AM"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:onClick="setTimeButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/timeBOne"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeBTwo"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/DayofWeek"
    android:text="01:30 AM"
    android:textSize="13sp" 
    android:onClick="setTimeButton"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/DayofWeek"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/timeBOne"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:text="Monday"
    android:textColor="#ECDFD5"
    android:textSize="35sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sunsD"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timeBOne"
    android:src="@drawable/sunshine" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/moonsD"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sunsD"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timeBSix"
    android:src="@drawable/moon" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timeBOne" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/switchOne"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timeBTwo" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchThree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeBThree"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/switchTwo" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchFour"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/switchThree"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timeBThree" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchSix"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/switchFive"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/timeBSix" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchSeven"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/switchSix"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timeBSix" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchEight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeBEight"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/switchSeven" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchNine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeBNine"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/switchEight" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchTen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeBTen"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/switchNine" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchFive"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/timeBFive"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/switchFour" />
```

Comment: Where is `s` variable definition?

Comment: Can you post your layout xml file?

Comment: in the class, defined as public Switch s

Comment: No problem with Buttom b is it? Post your xml as well

Comment: @Kartik I do not have a problem with Buttom b

Comment: How are your imports? Do you have some other class `Switch` referenced and not `android.widget.Switch`?

Comment: @laalto Indeed I have another class Switch. How do I fix this?

Comment: @user3725552 Just change import other.class.Switch; to import android.widget.Switch;

Comment: I fixed it! :) Thank you so much for all your help! Especially laalto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another `Switch` class in your project and the code is using that instead of `android.widget.Switch`.

If the other `Switch` is in another package, just change the imports to `import android.widget.Switch`.

If it is in the same package, you can explicitly refer to the platform class by replacing `Switch` with `android.widget.Switch` in code.